# Accessing parent with late static binding

Tags: php

I'd like to be able to get the late static binded class's parent.  I've written a non-functioning code example to clarify what I mean:

```
class A
{
    public static function getCombinedProperties()
    {
        $a = static::$properties; // Late static binding means this will work
        if(isset(static::parent::$properties))  // Calling static::parent obviously does not work
            $a = array_merge_recursive($a, static::parent::$properties);
        return $a;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static $properties = ['fruits' => ['pineapple', 'mango']];
}

class C extends B
{
    public static $properties = ['fruits' => ['apple', 'banana'], 'vegetables' => ['carrot', 'pea']];
}

B::getCombinedProperties(); //desired output ['fruits' => ['pineapple', 'mango']]
C::getCombinedProperties(); //desired output ['fruits' => ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'mango'], 'vegetables' => ['carrot', 'pea']]
```

Is it possible for class A get access to the $properties attribute of class B when the method is called from class C?

Comment: Naturally by just `static::` - not. Try `get_called_class()` to determine the called class then return the property from which class its needed

Comment: I have tried - using get_called_class() in the above example would return "C".  How to we then determine "B" to be its parent?  Using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, although it feels hacky:

```
class A
{
    public static function getCombinedProperties()
    {
        $a = static::$properties; // Late static binding means this will work
        $class = new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        $parent = $class->getParentClass();
        $parentName = $parent->getName();
        if(isset($parentName::$properties))
            $a = array_merge_recursive($a, $parentName::$properties);
        return $a;
    }
}
```